# OpenSuse - RubyGems install - wrong file names

Tags: ruby, linux, rubygems, opensuse

I have a fresh OpenSuse 13.1 installation with all updates installed.

`ruby -v` --> `ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27) [x86_64-linux]`
`gem -v`  --> `2.3.0`

Running `gem env` outputs following: `EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY`: `/usr/bin`. It is also in my `$PATH`.

I tried to install [`sass`](http://sass-lang.com/install) and [`compass`](http://compass-style.org/help/) as described by the installation guides:

```
sudo gem install sass
sudo gem install compass
```

*(I needed to use `sudo` because it didn't work without)*

Only problem: neither running the commands `sass` nor `compass` work.
After a while I figured out that I had to use `sass2.0` and `compass2.0` to run them. The ruby scripts in `/usr/bin` are named with `2.0` at the end of the filename.

Why are those ruby scripts named with `2.0` at the end? How can I prevent this? I would like to use just `compass` and `sass` in the terminal.

I didn't get any results using Google.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like openSUSE patches rubygems to keep multiple ruby versions installed, so it appends version number to files in bin/.

I've tried install sass package on my Linux x86_64 system and it produced `sass, scss and sass-convert` executables without extension.

I'd also warn to install gems this way, directly into filesystem. I'd recommend not avoiding package management and install through properly built packages. At openSUSE's wiki there is paragraph about [how to package Ruby gems into rpms](http://en.opensuse.org/openSUSE%3aPackaging_Ruby#How_to_package_Ruby_gems_into_rpms) .

Comment: Thanks. Because I'm not really into OpenSUSE nor into Open Build Service, I didn't package a ruby gem into a rpm. But because of that article (and some way more searching) I installed `rvm` (the article mentioned it) and installed the latest ruby version. Now `gem intall PACKAGE` installs the packages into my home directory (in `/home/USERNAME/.rvm/`). If you could add a note to `rvm`, I'll accept this answer. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 4):

There is a solution to this problem in this SeverFault Post: https://serverfault.com/questions/535450/install-gems-of-ruby-1-9-bins-without-suffix-in-opensuse

You have to add the parameter `--no-format-executable` the the `gem install` command. Since I did not want to clutter my system I installed sass like this:

```
gem install --install-dir ./gems --no-format-executable sass
```

Now I can execute it with `./gems/bin/sass`